# rsyslog sending data to remote slows down when $AddUnixListenSocket is used?

Tags: bind, rsyslog

I'm running a busy DNS server which logs queries to a remote server via rsyslog.

Due to the amount of traffic we're processing I've had to increase the rate limits in rsyslog.conf.
This server is processing at peak ~1.2K DNS requests/sec, which translates to ~2Mbps outgoing traffic to the remote logger.

However, when using the `$AddUnixListenSocket /var/named/chroot/dev/log` rsyslog directive I see a drastic decrease in data sent to the remote server.
Without this directive everything is fine, except that after an rsyslog restart the logging stops, requiring a restart of BIND as well.

It seems as if adding `$AddUnixListenSocket` "breaks" the rate limit increase in rsyslog. What's going on here?

Software versions:
  - CentOS 6.7 x86_64
  - rsyslog-5.8.10-10.el6_6.x86_64
  - bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.2.x86_64

My `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 10
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 15000
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 *
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

and `/etc/rsyslog.d/fwd.conf`:

```
# keep logging after rsyslog restart
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/named/chroot/dev/log

# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
$ActionQueueFileName tso_fwd # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueMaxFileSize 100M  # AF: limit open file descriptors
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionQueueTimeoutEnqueue 0  # AF: discard when queue is full
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
local0.* @@1.1.1.1:514
& ~
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that it was indeed ignoring the rate-limiting settings.

When I added `$AddUnixListenSocket` the input was changed to the `imuxsock` module, which has its own rate-limiting settings.

The top of `/etc/rsyslog.d/fwd.conf` looks like:

```
# raise logging limits
$IMUXSockRateLimitInterval 10
$IMUXSockRateLimitBurst 15000

# keep logging after rsyslog restart
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/named/chroot/dev/log
```

which fixed the issue.